# Add a new line upon new month in loop

Tags: php, foreach

I want to add a space when a new month is shown within a loop. `$item['date_expires']` is shown as year, month, and day (`YYYY-MM-DD`) within the loop.

```
<?php
    foreach($get_items AS $item) {
        $current = date('m', strtotime($item['date_expires']));

        if($current != date('m', strtotime($item['date_expires']))) {
            $new_month = true;
            $current = date('m', strtotime($item['date_expires']));
        }

        echo $item['date_expires'];

        echo $new_month == true ? '<br><br>' : '';
    }
?>
```

Here's how it's been shown now:

```
2018-11-27
2018-10-26
2018-09-25
2018-04-27
2018-04-09
2018-04-09
2018-04-05
2018-04-03
2018-04-02
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-03-30
2018-03-28
2018-03-28
2018-03-26
2018-03-26
2018-03-23
2018-03-21
2018-03-19
```

I want it to list the dates like this:

```
2018-11-27

2018-10-26

2018-09-25

2018-04-27
2018-04-09
2018-04-09
2018-04-05
2018-04-03
2018-04-02
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01
2018-04-01

2018-03-30
2018-03-28
2018-03-28
2018-03-26
2018-03-26
2018-03-23
2018-03-21
2018-03-19
```

What have I missed in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically because you were setting `$current` each time round the loop as the first thing you did the month was always the same.

See comments in code

```
<?php
    $current = null;    // init $current

    foreach($get_items AS $item) {
        // This set $current to the current rows date
        // every time round the loop so delete this line
        //$current = date('m', strtotime($item['date_expires']));

        if($current != date('m', strtotime($item['date_expires']))) {
            // output the newline here
            echo '<br>';
            // now reset $current to this rows dates month
            $current = date('m', strtotime($item['date_expires']));
        }

        echo $item['date_expires'];

        // now done in the loop so delete this line
        //echo $new_month == true ? '<br><br>' : '';
    }
?>
```

Comment: well i guess ill stop typing my answer then,wish i typed faster

Comment: @nogad Go for it, no reason we cannot upvote each others answer

Comment: nah its ok, its comically identical to yours :-)

Comment: Aha! So I only to change `$current` to null and move it above the loop. Many thanks! :)

Comment: I seem to have attracted a Downvoting troll. Care to explain yourself little troll